# What is the difference between "Gewitter" and "Ungewitter"?

Tags: meaning

I know that "Gewitter" means "Thunderstorm" and "Ungewitter" means "Violent storm", Could we say that Gewitter is a strom that have thunderbolt but Ungewitter **may** have thunderbolt?

Comment: I'm German and I had to google "Ungewitter". I've never heard it before....

Comment: Gewitter does not imply a storm at at all, merely thunder and bolts. Un(ge)witter would be a lot of wind and rain or snow, but not nessecairly any thunder

Comment: @Beta I think the other term would be _Unw**e**tter_ which refers to really bad wheather, including wind/storm, heavy rain, perhaps hail, thunder while _Gewitter_ is only thunder and bolts.

Comment: @Beta Exactly, you are right. I just wanted to stress on UnwEtter vs. Un(ge)wItter (e vs. i). Like Iris, I've never heard Ungewitter before.

Comment: And dict.cc indicates that "Ungewitter" = violent storm [mostly with heavy rains]. And that "Ungewitter" is an obsolete [veraltet] term.

Comment: There is no such word as "Ungewitter". The only two words are "Gewitter" and "Unwetter". "Gewitter" means "thunderstorms" and "Unwetter" just means "bad weather".

Comment: @StefanGruenwald: Like many others in here, I had never heard of it, either, but [yes, *Ungewitter* is a real word, it seems](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Ungewitter).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well "Gewitter" is something where you have thunder and lightnings, so it would be a thunderstorm in English. But a "Ungewitter" is an other form from "Unwetter" which could also be a thunderstorm, but more likely just bad weather with heavy winds and rain.

So a "Gewitter" is always a "Unwetter", but a "Unwetter" not always a "Gewitter".

But while speaking German "Ungewitter" is not that common, we mostly use "Unwetter" or just say there will be bad weather ("schlechtes Wetter").

Comment: Stimmt! Willkommen. Und als Muttersprachler habe ich "Ungewitter" noch nie gehört!

Comment: Ist aber ein deutsches Wort, so komisches es auch klingen mag.

Comment: Taking a look at [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Ungewitter%2CGewitter%2CUnwetter&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CUngewitter%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CGewitter%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CUnwetter%3B%2Cc0), it seems the word is pretty old and not used much nowadays. \[[also as an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/leTwA.png), for the benefit of mobile users]

Answer (score 5):

"Ungewitter" is a word for "Gewitter", not used anymore (I never heard it before. Duden and several other dictionaries say it's an old german term).
Usually we speak of a Gewitter or Unwetter.

[Duden defines](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Unwetter) "Unwetter" as follows [translated from german]: 
"Very bad, stormy weather, usualy with heavy rain [and thunderstorm]. Its intensity causes damages."

While "Gewitter" is [defined](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Gewitter) like this: "Storm ((in original it says even "Unwetter")) with lighting, thunder [and rain or similar]"

A Gewitter is a thunderstorm and Unwetter is a bad, stormy, weather condition in general, with or without Gewitter.

Answer (score 1):

Just google "Ungewitter": 389.000 hits. A frequent name, not a »Wetter«. But "Unwetter": nearly 10 million hits.